# Too many Opinion Based exchanges

Tags: discussion, stack-exchange

There seems to be a never-ending supply of new exchanges cropping up... however many of them have crossed into the realm of speculation and opinion, not fact based and absolute (like the original exchanges were intended as authoritative).

Are these allowed, and why? Some of the exchanges even seem to be redundant of one another, such as Mathematics Educator --> Academia or Mathematics. Will there eventually be a ____ Educator exchange for each type of subject? Workplace exchange in particular seems to be entirely opinion based as most questions involve "how to handle situation X" (the only thing I can see as factual in the Workplace exchange would be questions about labor laws, etc... but then this would cross over into legal advice)

Examples:

[How do you handle co-workers that want to converse with you in the bathroom?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/22802/how-do-you-handle-co-workers-that-want-to-converse-with-you-in-the-bathroom)

[Is it bad etiquette to ride road bike through a small residential area?](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/21174/is-it-bad-etiquette-to-ride-road-bike-through-a-small-residential-area)

[Just found out my 13 year old girl is Bi and dating a 17 year old girl in an "open" relationship. Huh? Now what?](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/12173/just-found-out-my-13-year-old-girl-is-bi-and-dating-a-17-year-old-girl-in-an-op)

[What do you think about the grammar of this quote ...?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/21399/what-do-you-think-about-the-grammar-of-this-quote)

[Is it considered ethical to accept payment from a business for reviewing a product or service?](https://writers.stackexchange.com/questions/10737/is-it-considered-ethical-to-accept-payment-from-a-business-for-reviewing-a-produ)

https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/36330/how-to-handle-player-knowledge-when-they-fumble-a-knowledge-roll

Comment: Whether it's on-topic or not is best addressed on the Metas of the specific sites.

Comment: @Bart the meta.stackexchange.com redirects here for the time being.

Comment: @SnakeDoc Not for long it won't ;)

Comment: Nah, each site has its own Meta. http://meta.workplace.stackexchange.com/ for example. The same goes for other sites. They have their own rules for what's on-topic and acceptable or not.

Comment: @Bart if that is true, the part about each exchange has it's own rules about opinion based answers, could you put that as an answer on this question? -- I was under the impression stackexchange is the parent for all exchanges, and therefore they all fall under the umbrella of striving to be an authoritative source for facts and direct answers. Workplace in particular is almost nothing but opinion. What about all the different language exchanges, like Spanish Language, English Language & Usage, English Language Learners, etc. Shouldn't they all be under a single umbrella Language exchange?

Comment: I think the point is that if you have a specific problem with a specific site, say so at that site.

Comment: @SnakeDoc each site is an independant community with its own guideliens and rules for questions.  Sure Stack Exchange runs them all, but it doesn't mean that the appropriate place to ask this question is on Meta-SE (formally know as Meta-SO).

Comment: that's a shame... what is meta.stackexchange.com for then? (I thought it was for network issues, such as this). I'll just drop it I suppose,... way to much energy to visit each of the 20 something exchanges and post the same question in each while citing examples only to get downvoted by the people using that very same [opinion-based] exchange that I'm arguing should be closed/merged.

Comment: @SnakeDoc primarily global issues affecting all sites.

Comment: "get downvoted by the people using that very same [opinion-based] exchange that I'm arguing should be closed/merged" -- yes, that's what is going to happen unless you can articulate the benefits of having those sites closed/merged. Which you haven't yet. Who stands to benefit from French and Japanese being mixed into one site, to begin with?

Comment: @cheapeffectivedietpills He doesn't seem to be arguing a merger of those sites, but an "umbrella" of language sites which all have the same rules/regulations as to what is appropriate.

Comment: Yes, and furthermore, regarding the opinion based exchanges such as Workplace, I don't imagine I'd be able to tread water by making a case on their meta about closing their exchange.. the people using Workplace exchange (and Meta Workplace) are there for the opinions since a glance of the answered questions indicates something like only 5% of them are factual based. Just feels like it's turning into another Yahoo Answers instead of a place I can reasonably assume I'm reading factual material.

Comment: Every site deserves the time to establish their own rules for what's on topic and what's not.  Including the sites you already know, SO sucked pretty heavy for well over a year.  If you don't like what you see then act like an atheist looking at a site meant for christians, nothing to see there unless you like aggravation.

Comment: I know where you're coming from, but at root I think the question is "what's the harm?" Does it affect the less-subjective sites? I don't think it does, so we just live and let live. It's SE's business and problem at the end of the day.

Comment: Also, are you familiar with ["Good Subjective, Bad Subjective"](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/09/good-subjective-bad-subjective/)?

Comment: @JoshCaswell well, the harm, one could argue, is that it dilutes the authoritative nature of the network. -- at least in the early days, the network tried hard to differentiate itself from all of the forums sites that it argued were "broken". but today exchanges like Workplace are filled with "disposable" questions that don't apply to anyone except the OP and generally are not going to serve as an authoritative record of "how to do X".

Comment: But does having read a few SUBJECTIVESITE.SE questions and decided the site sucked make it less likely that someone will trust Stack Overflow?

Comment: @JoshCaswell idk, it's possible if it's someone's first impression... but that is speculation. imho stackoverflow is a shining example of how all exchanges should be run.. SO has every programming language and every programming paradigm umbrella-ed under it... if you have a programming question about "how to do x?" -- there is no question about which exchange to post on, nor a question about how factual and correct the answers will be. Imagine if they were split up like Game Development, Board & Card Games, Role-playing Games and Arqade (all  related)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Are these allowed, and why?

Yes, obviously those sites are allowed. There was enough community support on Area 51 to get them started, so Stack Exchange is giving those communities a chance to make their sites work.

> Some of the exchanges even seem to be redundant of one another, such as Mathematics Educator --> Academia or Mathematics.

Those are three different topics. There really aren't many questions that would be on-topic on two of those sites. Read their respective Help centers for guidance on what kinds of questions are accepted on each one.

> Will there eventually be a ____ Educator exchange for each type of subject?

I suspect there will be if the Math Educator site takes off successfully.

> Workplace exchange in particular seems to be entirely opinion based as most questions involve "how to handle situation X" (the only thing I can see as factual in the Workplace exchange would be questions about labor laws, etc... but then this would cross over into legal advice)

Yes, I agree. People wanted a place to ask these types of questions, which were continually being closed on other Stack Exchange sites. Personally, I'd much rather see sites like this given a chance to survive than see people keep asking off-topic questions on other SE sites just to have them closed. If the site fails, so be it. If it succeeds, fantastic.

Comment: Well, [workplace.se] just moved out of beta - which it probably wouldn't if there isn't a chance that it can succeed.

Comment: Do you think there may be a time to tag such exchanges as primarily opinion-based, and/or questions with a similar tag? Googling for something and winding up on an exchange with answers spoken as fact but are actually opinion can be deceiving/misleading to some (all?)

Comment: No SE site is only opinion based (at least AFAIK, but there are too many of them). Most sites require at least some kind of backup, not just a personal opinion, questions should be useful for further readers etc.

Comment: (cc @JohannesKuhn) [workplace.se] was actually in beta for, like, three years before it recently graduated. It clearly has staying power.

Comment: @michaelb958, just to clarify the facts, Workplace SE was in beta for less than 2 years. The site's public beta began on April 17th, 2012, and it graduated on February 20th, 2014. Three days ago was it's two year anniversary.

Comment: @jmort253 Trust me to misremember dates by that margin… Nonetheless, it's been around for quite a while.